# Phonegap build refuses to update my app when I upload a new zip file

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I am using Phonegap Build to build for IOS/Android. Just a test app at the moment but I am confused. I compress my app folder:

```
myApp/
    config.xml
    /www
        index.html
        index.js
myApp.zip <- I create the zip file at this level (only main files shown here)
```

My problem is, I have completely changed the index.html and index.js file, re-zipped the files, uploaded them to PhoneGap Build, but it insists on showing the original index.html file and executed the original index.js file. Locally, using the PhoneGap app on my iPhone I can see the changes when browsing on my ip address at :3000 but PhoneGap refuses to see that I've made a change. VERY frustrating. Anyone have any ideas how I can force PhoneGap Build to wake up and smell the coffee? I have completely deleted the app via the web interface and re-built and it STILL shows the old version. Any help appreciated,

thanks in advance,

Wittner

Answer (score 2):

Ok I think this might be the answer. It's been a while since I worked with PhoneGap and I used a boilerplate code and structure for my tests. I moved the config.xml inside the www directory and compressed the files from inside it. Uploading this now works.

Comment: yes, afaik, config.xml needs to be in www and upload the www.zip to phonegap build.